# WordPress user database to Node sqlite database

Tags: node.js, wordpress, sqlite, hash, salt

I am in the processing of importing a WordPress user database (titled `wp_dnsy_users`) to a new sqlite database used in Node js. My question is will I / how will I be able to verify passwords and figure out which node crypto or other algorithm to use?

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of WordPress are using Portable PHP password hashing framework for password hashes. 
You can find node.js implementation of that framework here: https://github.com/jhurliman/node-phpass